# Find all possible overlap and non-overlaps from list of various ranges of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

With the following code I can determine the 
overlap range, give list of ranges (tuple). List size can vary.
It this example the list has 3 tuples.

```
ranges = [(10,20), (15,25), (18,30)]
starts, ends = zip(*ranges)
result = range(max(starts), min(ends) + 1)
print(*result)
# 18 19 20
```

Now what I want to  is also to find the **non-overlap**. With the same
input ranges. It yields:

```
(10,11,12,13,14)
(26,27,28,29,30)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So is your range tuples sorted? or is always `max(starts)` lower than  `min(ends)`?

Comment: @Kasramvd: Unsorted.

Comment: So you want the ranges that don't overlap at all, not just the ones that only overlap two of three? Is it guaranteed there'll be some overlap?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the question my answer *does* answer it. If the results aren't what you want please include some more inputs and the outputs you'd want.  Or define formally when a number `x` is overlapping according to a list of ranges and when a number `x` is not overlapping. My definitions are: `x` overlaps with `ranges` if and only if `all(x in range(s, e+1) for (s, e) in ranges)` and `x` does not overlap if `any(x not in range(s, e+1) for (s, e) in ranges)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html):

```
range(*heapq.nsmallest(2, starts))   # -> 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
end, start = heapq.nlargest(2, ends)
range(start+1, end)   # 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

Note however that this will only work if the overlap is non-empty.

When you have an empty overlap you can simply obtain the "non-overlap" by doing:

```
range(min(starts), max(ends))
```

i.e. it's the whole range.

So, if you wanted a function you'd get:

```
def find_overlap_and_non_overlap(ranges):
    starts, ends = zip(*ranges)
    overlap = range(max(starts), min(ends)+1)
    if not overlap:
        return ([], range(min(starts), max(ends)+1), [])

    less_non_overlap = range(*heapq.nsmallest(2, starts))
    end, start = heapq.nlargest(2, ends)
    greater_non_overlap = range(start+1, end+1)
    return (overlap, less_non_overlap, greater_non_overlap)
```

Which for you sample input returns:

```
In[5]: find_overlap_and_non_overlap(ranges)
Out[5]: (range(18, 21), range(10, 15), range(26, 31))
In [6]: list(map(list, find_overlap_and_non_overlap(ranges)))
Out[6]: [[18, 19, 20], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]
```

The first element is the overlapping values, the second the non-overlapping values that come before the overlap and the last element are the non-overlapping values that come after the overlap.
If the overlap is empty all values are put in the second element of the tuple.

---

If you want to obtain the overlap/non-overlap of *pairs* of ranges you can simply repeatedly call the function:

```
results = []

for a in ranges:
    for b in ranges:
        if a != b:
            results.append(find_overlap_and_non_overlap([a, b]))
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I turn that into function with `ranges = [(10,20), (15,25), (18,30)]` as input and output is list of tuples?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Almost perfect solution! But I tried this: `ranges = [(10,20), (10,18), (15,25), (18,30)]` Where there is one range that overlaps with first segments. It doesn't give result as expected.

Comment: @neversaint it returns the result that **I** expect. the only overlap over all the ranges is `[18]`. You have to clarified what do you want. My answer is about finding the overlap of *all* the ranges and the non-overlap of *all* the ranges.

Comment: Overlap and non overlap of all possible range intersection.

Comment: @neversaint So you want, for each pair of ranges, the overlap and non-overlap between them? You should obtain this result by simply doing: `for a in ranges: for b in ranges: if a != b: print(find_overlap_non_overlap([a, b]))`. Or maybe you then want to merge the overlaps of these calls?